# How to test MAPI Send Email errors

Tags: email, delphi, outlook, mapi

We have a program written in Delphi that can send emails via simple MAPI
for the people that use MAPI with outlook installed 95% of the time it works fine

but for the 5% of people that it doesn't just work for is there anyway to Test MAPI
looking for something where we can find if there is an issue with our program or if its something that their hardware guy needs to fix.
Would be good if its some Microsoft tool or something official so if we go to the clients hardware/IT guy and say test this he will trust the results of the test

**some errors we have come across include**

api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Access violation only for one contact in the outlook address book - happened when calling the MAPIResolveName (no solution found for this - client didnt want to reinstall outlook)

Mapi error 26 for Office build version 1703 - first email goes through ok but they all fail after that.  (You can make a work around by using the MapiLogOn and pass the session handle through in the MAPISendMail call)

Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request